# Why do I have such slow experience in web browsing on Ubuntu?

Tags: flash

I have a relatively recent laptop with decent hardware and on Windows web browsing is pretty good, but when on ubuntu, it gets so slow, I can't watch properly a video from youtube or even low quality videos from elsewhere, which lag all the time. Also images take more time to load. I've tried everything, my firefox has adblock plus, flashblock, I use flashgot to download videos and watch them on a player but I can't be downloading several MB Long videos all the time. I've tried Chromium, Firefox and Opera, Opera is the one that allows me to have more tabs open without freezing, however Flash problems remain. Chromium crashes all the time with the "aww snap" page.

On an older PC I have with Lubuntu, it's even worse, I can't open a window with a video because it will freeze the system entirely until it loads, I often have to go to windows XP if I want to browse decently. What can I do to have a better web experience?

Comment: You haven't mentioned what your hardware actually is. For instance, I have a Lenovo Thinkpad x100e, with a 1.5 AMD (single core) processor, 4GB RAM, ATI RADEON. I have never enjoyed full HD video or youtube while on ubuntu. Lagging most of the time. I pretty much believe it is graphic card related. Aww snap! happens often when the lappy gets slow or when multiple tabs are open.

Comment: I did not mention my hardware because for example youtube videos play just fine even on my old desktop Pentium IV running WinXP SP3 with only 1GB Ram and with more than 5 opened tabs, while I can't even watch a low quality video on my laptop with Ubuntu, Intel Dual Core and 4GB of RAM without lag and crashes. So I assumed it was related to flash itself or its compatibility with linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple factors involved. If it's just to watch youtube, you may want to try `Totem`, it has a youtube plugin. If you have the package `totem-mozilla` installed, it'll hijack all flash video in your web browser. Youtube will play just fine, but then say goodbye to online flash games, etc. Other options are trying [Gnash](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnash/) or [Lightspark](http://lightspark.github.com/). Gnash is in the repositories and Lightspark can easily [installed via PPA](http://www.unixmen.com/lightspark-a-good-alternative-to-adobe-flash-player-ppa-ubuntu-fedora-rpm/). There's also the option of viewing a fair deal in HTML5.

Also how much RAM do you have? Are you loading the same number of tabs in the same web browser in both Ubuntu and windows? I find Firefox to handle multiple tabs better than Chrome/Chromium, don't really use Opera.

To make sure you can browse decently (any OS)

- make sure all hardware is properly configured
- use a [good hosts file](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=241460) - not kidding this does make a difference, even if you're not scared of viruses on Ubuntu

Another thing you can try is a lighter browser such as Epiphany or Midori, mind you I find both to be less stable than Firefox.

Comment: I have no problems with flash or loading webpages on both Windows 7 (4GB RAM laptop) and Windows XP SP3 (old 1GB RAM desktop, on this one I must have only few opened tabs). This only happens on Ubuntu, with two different PC's, different configurations, the same problems, so that's why I made this question, I excluded that it could be hardware or drivers related. I also got surprised with Opera but indeed is the browser that gives me better experience while browsing on Linux... I tried it precisely because chromium and firefox were both too sluggish, but then I can't use all my Firefox add-ons.

Comment: Is slow browsing and browser crashing only occurring when you're using Flash? I'm not blaming your hardware specs (unless you have hardware malfunctions such as RAM errors, which is something you can test), I've got Flash working fairly well on Pentium 4's with 512 MB RAM, but how many tabs you can use depends on the RAM you've got.